# Writing a non-deterministic Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, automata

I got an exercise in my college in which ive been asked to write a **Non deterministic** Turing Machine that accepts words of this form:[image]

Ive manage to find some sort of solution but in a Deterministic way

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Then your solution is prefectly valid. A deterministic turing machine is *also* a non-deterministic turing machine, since deterministic turing machines form a subset of the non-deterministic ones.